# query views code (definitions)

Tags: database, oracle, view

I am trying to find some views which have a comment in them - in the code! - (something like '--TO DO'), but the problem is that I don't know the views names and to look at each by hand would take me a whole lot of time (I have over 2k views). 
So I am trying to make a query that will search in the view's code for the text of interest.

I managed to come up with something like this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM ALL_SOURCE
 WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE UPPER('%my_text_here%')
ORDER BY name desc
```

But this doesn't query my views. It queries the functions, the procedures, packages, triggers...pretty much everything except the views...which I find pretty odd. 
At first I thought that maybe there were no views that contained that keyword so I changed to some basic SQL keywords that I knew for sure exist...and still no results.

Anyone could tell me what am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views are stored in `all_views` (also: `dba_views` or `user_views`, depending on your access and needs).  However, the text column in all_views is a long, which means you'll first have to convert it to a Clob before you can use it in your query.  The easiest work around ([from Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:510622111991)) would be to create a new table in your schema and convert the Longs into Clobs like this:

```
create table myviews as 
select  owner, view_name, to_lob(text) as text from all_views;
```

Then select from your own table:

```
select * 
  from myviews
  where upper(text) like upper('%my_text_here%') 
order by view_name desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...one little question please..i am not sure I understand what you mean by limiting my options?

Comment: @relysis Long columns are "special"... you can't perform many of the actions that you thought you should be able to like have them as arguments in functions (e.g. upper, substr, instr), (unless that function specifically takes a Long as an argument). Long's are deprecated in favor of Lobs, but Oracle uses Longs on many of their internal tables, which makes working around the limitations on Longs a necessity.

Comment: @relysis I should also mention that to_lob() MUST return into storage, usually on disk, (e.g. insert, update)... select to_lob(text) from all_views; isn't supported, so most solutions usually involve a table to store the converted results. If this is a permanent solution, a global temporary table may be a potential solution.